# Why can't `Table` member implement underlying interface `ITable` member?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, inheritance, mocking, repository

I'm experimenting with the following mockable repository pattern:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    ITable<Employee> Employees { get; }
}
```

This represents a container capable of returning an `ITable` of `Employee` objects.  I want to be able to create a mock object based off of the repository, as well as have my Linq-to-Sql `DataContext` implement the repository interface.  So I thought I could just use partial class to declare my `DataContext` type to implement `IEmployeeRepository`, as it already has an auto-generated member `Employees` of type `Table<Employee>`:

```
public partial class MyDataContext : IEmployeeRepository { }
```

I get the following error message as a result:

> 'MyDataContext' does not implement interface member
>   'IEmployeeRepository.Employees'. 'MyDataContext.Employees' cannot
>   implement 'IEmployeeRepository.Employees' because it does not have the
>   matching return type of 'System.Data.Linq.ITable'.

But `Table<Employee>` inherits `ITable<Employee>`, so shouldn't it be a suitable return type to implement the interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Interface not implemented" when Returning Derived Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121283/interface-not-implemented-when-returning-derived-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementing class' type must match the interface type exactly. If you can't change the interface, you could implement it explicitly:

```
class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    // existing property
    public Table<Employee> Employees { get; }

    // explicit IEmployeeRepository property
    ITable<Employee> IEmployeeRepository.Employees { get { return Employees; } }
}
```

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought of that.  I did try exposing a renamed property `EmployeesRepository`, which does essentially the same thing and returns the underlying property, but here you are able to keep the name the same, which I prefer.