# Implement EntitySet as IList

Tags: c#, linq, repository-pattern

Im playing with LinqToSql and im trying to implement the Repository pattern for one of my classes. The problem  comes when i try to map a property that is EntitySet to IList i get an error

> 'TheCore.Models.User' does not implement interface member 'TheCore.Models.IUserRepository.Vehicles'. 'TheCore.Models.User.Vehicles' cannot implement 'TheCore.Models.IUserRepository.Vehicles' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

The EntitySet seems to implement IList so why can't I map the IList property to the EntitySet property?

The EntitySet:

```
        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Users_Vehicles", Storage="_Vehicles", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="FkOwnerId")]
    public EntitySet<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Vehicles;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Vehicles.Assign(value);
        }
    }
```

The repository interface:

```
        IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

Comment: i would use entity framework instead of linqtosql

Comment: i wanted to try how it feels using linqtosql :)

Comment: i think you need to map between source (entity set) to list type. use automapper or some other mapping libraries for that.

Comment: Don't waste your time with LINQ to SQL. Honestly, it would be more beneficial for you to learn Entity Framework. Although L2S had it fans, things have moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the implementation of the interface must match the return type declared in the interface. This is called return type covariance and it is not supported by C#.

So the code below doesn't work even though `List` implements `IList`

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IList<string> Foos {get; set;}
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public List<string> Foos {get; set;}
}
```

Have a look at this question: ["Interface not implemented" when Returning Derived Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121283/interface-not-implemented-when-returning-derived-type)

Answer (score 1):

I'm possibly not understanding your question, but it appears you have an interface with a method `IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }` and trying to fulfil the contract by providing an implementation `public EntitySet<Vehicle> Vehicles`. This isn't allowed - the implementation must provide the same return type as the interface (`IList<Vehicle>` in this case). If you can, change your repository implementation to wrap the EntitySet and then match the method to the required interface:

```
public class Vehicle
{
}
public interface IRepository
{
    IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private EntitySet<Vehicle> _Vehicles;
    public IList<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Vehicles;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Vehicles.Assign(value);
        }
    }
}
```