# Why is there no implicit casting of return types when implementing an interface?

Tags: c#

The following is not allowed by the C# compiler. It says that Cool's implementation of ICool's Jello method does not return an IObject. But Object is an IObject. Why is this not supported?

```
interface ICool
{
    IObject Jello();
}

interface IObject
{

}

class Cool : ICool
{
    public Object Jello() { return new Object(); }
}

class Object : IObject
{

}
```

Comment: Works just fine here. Don't name it `Object` because that name is already taken and is likely the cause of the problem: you're using the wrong `Object` class.

Comment: I apologize. I posted an edited version. This is the correct version. Cool returns Object.

Comment: Just posted the code that doesn't work!

Comment: Yep, this is indeed a duplicate. Thank you for pointing to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a workaround to C# not supporting return type covariance (see ["Interface not implemented" when Returning Derived Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121283/interface-not-implemented-when-returning-derived-type) ):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CsharpFun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object obj = (Object) new Cool().Jello();
        }
    }

    interface ICool<T> where T : IObject
    {
        T Jello();
    }

    interface IObject
    {

    }

    class Cool : ICool<Object>
    {
        public Object Jello() { return new Object(); }
    }

    class Object : IObject
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you believe this is information that isn't present anywhere else, you should add it to the post that this is a duplicate of to keep valuable answers grouped together.